# Export SPL Token Holders

Tags: spl-token, solana-cli

What is the easiest way to do the following:

Provide the mint address

Get back all the token holders of that mint, including their token balance and token balance in US Dollars.

(The US Dollar balance is not a strict requirement, but it would be nice.)

In an ideal world, an online website would have been ideal, insert the mint address and get back a CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of sites that have solutions like this. One example is [Famous Fox Federation's Snapshot tool](https://famousfoxes.com/snapshot).

[image: FFF Snapshot Example]